# How to search for multiple strings in very large database

Tags: oracle, lucene, bigdata, fuzzy-search, string-search

I want to search for multiple strings in a very large database. These strings are part of different attributes of database table. I have tried string search using `LIKE` in sql query. But it is taking a lot of time to get results. I have used Oracle database.

Should I use indexing of database? I found that `Lucene` can be used for it.
I also got some suggestions of using big data concepts. Which approach should I use?

Comment: How about Oracle text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is:
1.) adding an index to the columns you like to search trough
2.) using oracle text as @lalitKumarB wrote

The most powerful way is:
3.) use an separate search engine (solr, elaticsearch).

But, probably you have to change you application in order to explicit use the search index for searching trough the data,...

I had the same situation some years before. Trying to search text in an big database. After a wile I found out, that database based search will never reach the performance of an dedicate search engine. And: you will have much more search features working out of the box, if you use solr (for example), like spelling correction, "More like this", ...

One option is to hold the data on orcale, searching in solr and return the ID of the document in order to only load the one row form oracle, the is referenced by the ID.
2nd option is to keep oracle as base datapool for your search engine and search in solr (or elasticsearch) in order to return the whole document/row from solr, not only the ID. So you don't need to load the data from the database any more.

The best option depends on your needs.

Comment: @hp36 please mark this answer as correct, if it is the most helpful one.

Comment: can we use fuzzy string matching in elaticsearch or solr

Comment: Which one is better for fuzzy searching(or approximate string searching)- elaticsearch or solr....  @The Bndr

Comment: I don't know all the features of elasticsearch. Both uses lucene. So they have the same base. As far as I know, elasticsearch is better in scaling than solr cloud. But Solr has a bit more or better working features. Solr is able to this. `pairs~` <- find terms like `paris`, `pairs`, ....  or `newslattar~0.5 '  <- find term with an approximate 50% Value. In Solr 'approximate  searching' for string and phrases works. Probably elasticsearch also can do this.

Comment: I have found a link for comparison between elaticsearch and solr...

[Click here](http://solr-vs-elasticsearch.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You have the choice between elasticsearch, solr or lucene

Comment: lucene is an library, while solr and elaticsearch are applications that used lucene

Comment: we can develop something over lucene, no?

Comment: of cause. But It looks like, the the "lucene"-world is new for @hp36. So it could be happens, that someone treat lucene equivalent as an application, like solr. Lucene is not an out-of-the-box working solution like solr. That is, why I wrote this comment.